# What is pseudo decorator design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

There are few mentions on the web about "pseudo decorator" pattern. For example:

> So what we have is an example of how to extend sObject functionality in Apex with behavior at runtime, rather than through inheritance using a pseudo decorator pattern.

*Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Conclusion_3*

Is there a formal definition for it? How is it different from normal decorator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific case, it is different from the default implementation for the fact that the decorator and the decorated class do not implement a common interface.
This is usually required so that a client that receives an instance of a class that implements the interface `I` doesn't care about the fact that it's an instance of a base class or of a decorated one.

This is instead an alternative version of the decorator where composition is preferred over inheritance.
You cannot rely on polymorphism and virtual functions as it happens in the decorator pattern. Instead, users has a reference to the outermost class and this one actually enriches the interface of the innermost class.

That's why it is called *pseudo-decorator*. The purpose is more or less the same, but the implementation differs from the one of the original pattern.